# How to handle multiple callbacks in ASP.Net 4.0 C#? Example

Tags: c#, asp.net, callback

I have to handle two callbacks in one page one on button event and other on List.

When button 'showDate' is clicked it display Time
 and when button 'btnlookup' is clicked it show the respective value of listbox item.. below is my code HTML & .cs file

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script language="javascript">
        function ReceiveResults(arg, context) 
        {
            showDate.innerHTML = arg;
        }

        function LookUpStock() {
            var lb = document.getElementById("ListBox1");
            var product = lb.options[lb.selectedIndex].text;
            CallServer2(product, "");
        }

        function ReceiveServerData(rValue) {
            document.getElementById("ResultsSpan").innerHTML = rValue;

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <span id="showDate">aaa</span>
        </br>
        <input id="btnShowDate" type="button" value="getDate"  onclick="CallServer();"/>

    </div>

        <div>
      <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" Runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
      <br />
      <br />
      <button type="btnLookUP" onclick="LookUpStock()">Look Up Stock</button>
      <br />
      <br />
      Items in stock: <span id="ResultsSpan" runat="server"></span>
      <br />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Code for .cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class callback : System.Web.UI.Page, ICallbackEventHandler
{
   protected String returnValue;
   protected String myDate;
   protected System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary catalog;


    public String GetCallbackResult()
    {
        //return returnValue;
        return myDate;
    }

    public void RaiseCallbackEvent(String eventArgument)
    {
        myDate = System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();


        //if (catalog[eventArgument] == null) 
        //{
        //    returnValue = "-1";
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    returnValue = catalog[eventArgument].ToString();
        //}
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //For Time
        ClientScriptManager cSM = Page.ClientScript;
        String myCBRefrence = cSM.GetCallbackEventReference(this, "arg", "ReceiveResults", "context");
        cSM.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "CallServer", "function CallServer(arg, context) {" + myCBRefrence + ";}", true);

        //callback back for listbox
            //String cbReference = Page.ClientScript.GetCallbackEventReference(this, "arg", "ReceiveServerData", "context");
            //String callbackScript = "function CallServer2(arg, context){ " + cbReference + ";}";
            //Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "CallServer2", callbackScript, true);

            //catalog = new System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary();
            //catalog.Add("monitor", 12);
            //catalog.Add("laptop", 10);
            //catalog.Add("keyboard", 23);
            //catalog.Add("mouse", 17);

            //ListBox1.DataSource = catalog;
            //ListBox1.DataTextField = "key";
            //ListBox1.DataBind();

    }
}
```

Code which is comments is for the second callback event, Problem is in this code is that i can only raise one callback, can someone tell me what changes i need to make in code so that i can raise both callback event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a piece of personal advice: do not write JavaScript in your C# code. This will get **very** messy and **very** hard to debug quickly.

If you really need to get this information, you should use an ASP.NET Web Service (a .asmx file). You can call these Web Services using JavaScript or jQuery (I prefer jQuery myself).

If I had a .asmx file like so:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class ServerTime : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string Get()
    {
        return System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }
}
```

I would call that using the following jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", dataType: "json", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "ServerTime.asmx/Get",
    success: function (result) {
        $("#showDate").html(result.d);
    }
});
```

Note that `success` is deprecate din the latest version of jQuery, but I can't find a good example of `done` online.

Comment: I agree with you but writing web service for small function will make things difficult at times I am not sure if it is good practice. What if i want to invoke 4-5 methods in code-behind file using callback, What should be the best approach for that?. I am still learning . Let me rephrase my question suppose if i have a page with 4 btn & each btn gets certain information without postback what should be the best practice that one should follow

Comment: Writing web services for small functions doesn't make things difficult. That doesn't make sense. Using callbacks like this is a bad approach. ASMX WebServices or WCF interfaces are the only solutions you should consider.

Comment: Agree with you, So i will mark this as correct answer. Thanks